# Solving $n$ degree polynomial equation with value of $n$ and $a$

Tags: polynomials

I need solve values of $w$ for $n=5$ and $a=0.6$. I need to find values of $w$ which satisfy this equation with different $n$ and $a$ values.

$$\ w*((n-1)a+1-n\times w)^n=((n-1)a)^{n-1} \times (((n-1)a-n)w+1)$$

Comment: Do you want to solve the equation for $n = 5, a = 0.6 i$ or for **any** value of $n, a$?

Comment: no. i want values of w which satisfies the equation for n=5 and a=0.6 and also the method name or step

Comment: The parenthesing is not balanced. Please fix the expression before we start looking at it.

Comment: @Bhaumik In terms of fraction, it is $$w\left(\frac{17}{5} - 5w\right)^5 = \frac{20736}{625} \left(-\frac{13}{5} w + 1\right)$$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i want values of w real and imaginary , which satisfy this equation with n=5 and a=0.6

Comment: @AlexVong  yes  you are right. i have applied binomial theorem and i got polynomial of w with degree 6 . i don' t know how to solve that equation ?

Comment: @Bhaumik Can you show us the degree $6$ polynomial you obtained?

Comment: @AlexVong sorry it is 5th degree polynomial .

Comment: @Bhaumik I am afraid this is not correct: $$\left(\frac{17}{5} - 5w\right)^5 = -3125w^5 + 10625w^4 - 14450w^3 + 9826w^2 -\frac{83521}{25}w + \frac{1419857}{3125}$$

Comment: @AlexVong   help me with this kind of equation. $$\ 540.6157*w-668.168*w^2+982.6*w^3-1445*w^4+2125*w^5 -3215*w^6-33.1776=0 $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, substituting $n = 5, a = \frac{3}{5}$ into the equation gives
$$w\left(\frac{17}{5} - 5w\right)^5 = \frac{20736}{625} \left(-\frac{13}{5}w + 1\right)$$
Multiple both sides by $5^5 = 625 \cdot 5$ gives
$$w(17 - 25w)^5 = 20736\left(-13w + 5\right)$$
Factoring composite numbers
$$w(17 - 5^2w)^5 = 2^8 3^4\left(-13w + 5\right)$$
Expanding on both sides
$$w\left(-5^{10} w^5 + 5 \cdot 17 \cdot 5^8 w^4 - 10 \cdot 17^2 \cdot 5^6 w^3 + 10 \cdot 17^3 \cdot 5^4 w^2 - 5 \cdot 17^4 \cdot 5^2 w + 17^5 \right) \\ = -2^8 \cdot 3^4 \cdot 13 w + 2^8 \cdot 3^4 \cdot 5$$
Factoring composite numbers
$$w\left(-5^{10} w^5 + 5^9 \cdot 17 w^4 - 2 \cdot 5^7 \cdot 17^2 w^3 + 2 \cdot 5^5 \cdot 17^3 w^2 - 5^3 \cdot 17^4 w + 17^5 \right) \\ = -2^8 \cdot 3^4 \cdot 13 w + 2^8 \cdot 3^4 \cdot 5$$
Put everything to one side
$$5^{10} w^6 - 5^9 \cdot 17 w^5 + 2 \cdot 5^7 \cdot 17^2 w^4 - 2 \cdot 5^5 \cdot 17^3 w^3 + 5^3 \cdot 17^4 w^2 - 17^5 w - 2^8 \cdot 3^4 \cdot 13 w + 2^8 \cdot 3^4 \cdot 5 = 0$$
Combining like terms
$$5^{10} w^6 - 5^9 \cdot 17 w^5 + 2 \cdot 5^7 \cdot 17^2 w^4 - 2 \cdot 5^5 \cdot 17^3 w^3 + 5^3 \cdot 17^4 w^2 - 5^2 \cdot 67577 w + 2^8 \cdot 3^4 \cdot 5 = 0$$
Divide both sides by $5$
$$5^{9} w^6 - 5^8 \cdot 17 w^5 + 2 \cdot 5^6 \cdot 17^2 w^4 - 2 \cdot 5^4 \cdot 17^3 w^3 + 5^2 \cdot 17^4 w^2 - 5 \cdot 67577 w + 2^8 \cdot 3^4 = 0$$
and let $$p(w) = 5^{9} w^6 - 5^8 \cdot 17 w^5 + 2 \cdot 5^6 \cdot 17^2 w^4 - 2 \cdot 5^4 \cdot 17^3 w^3 + 5^2 \cdot 17^4 w^2 - 5 \cdot 67577 w + 2^8 \cdot 3^4$$
Now by rational root theorem, any rational root of $p(w)$ must be of the form $\frac{p}{q}$, where $p$ is a factor of $2^8 \cdot 3^4$ and $q$ is a factor of $5^{9}$. Since there is a peculiar amount of $5$ in $p(w)$, why not try $p = 1, q = 5$. It turns out $p(\frac{1}{5}) = 0$ and $p'(\frac{1}{5}) = 0$ where $p'(w)$ is the derivative of $p(w)$. So $(5w - 1)^2 = 25 w^2 - 10w + 1$ is a factor of $p(w)$. Using long division for polynomial, one can show that $$p(w) = (5w - 1)^2 q(w)$$ where $$q(w) = 5^7 w^4 - 3 \cdot 5^7 w^3 + 3^2 \cdot 5^4 \cdot 47 w^2 - 5^2 \cdot 23 \cdot 227 w + 2^8 \cdot 3^4$$ So we reduce the problem to solving a quartic equation. (To be continued$\dots$)